# Apple Pay Register domain API issue

Tags: safari, applepay, applepayjs

We tried to register domain using this endpoint `https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/paymentservices/registerMerchant` and the request is:

```
{ 
"domainNames": ["domain-name"], 
"encryptTo": "merchant-id", 
"partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier": "merchant-id", 
"partnerMerchantName": "merchant-name" 
}
```

but we get this response:

```
{ 
"statusMessage": "Payment Services Exception The number of domains for the merchant `merchant-id` the allowed limit99", 
"statusCode": "400" 
}
```

but we just send one domain.
If anyone face this issue before, can you please tell us how to fix it?

**Update - The solution:**

The error message response is not entirely correct because, according to Apple's documentation, you can register a domain as you wish with the same merchant ID. However, we've found that the problem is not with the merchant ID but with `partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier`, which is limited to 99. So, you need to change this property when you reach the limit of 99. It's important to note that you should use `partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier` to initiate a payment session, not the main `merchant-id`.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Kibartas Yes, the response error message is not correct on total, because as Apple documentation your can register domain as you want by same merchant-id, but we found the problem not in merchant id the problem in `partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier` this is limited for 99, so you need to change this property when you limit to 99, but note -this important- you should use `partnerInternalMerchantIdentifier` to initiate payment session not the main on `merchant-id`.